# Connection bug with socket.io-client (Server to Server)

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a problem with socket.io-client normaly when i connect my clientWS to the ServerWS it try to connect in loop even if the ServerWS is not started.

I tried it in a simple node app and it work, but when I'm trying to include it in another project i got this error:

```
.../node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js:75
    this.nsps[nsp].emit.apply(this.nsps[nsp], arguments);
                        ^
TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined
    at Manager.emitAll (.../node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js:75:25)
    at null._onTimeout (.../node_modules/socket.io-client/lib/manager.js:464:12)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:110:15)
16 Mar 21:54:03 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

And it's the same connection code in both project :

```
var socket = require("socket.io-client");
var ws = socket("http://localhost:3000");
```

So I don't know what is the problem...

(tested with socket.io and socket.io-client 1.3.5)

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to actually serve your websocket connection?  I could be wrong, but what you've provided looks like it's only the client code.

Comment: Cause it's only the client code the problem.. if the server is up everything is fine but if he is down i cant start the client.. normally the client try to connect/reconnect infinitely and store all emitted event in a buffer

but now it just break and raise this error...

Comment: The sample node app you had success with, do the npm versions match up with the ones in this project?

Comment: Just realize my comment didn't work... I found the source of my problem ! In my code i define some extension to Object there is a problem of compatibility.. idk how to resolve this :/

Comment: Our ability to give answers is limited until you provide more code

Comment: I define some Object.prototype and this make for...in.. loop bug :) And socket.io-client use this kind of for loop without using hasOwnPropertie so yep found the source of the problem